# why my controls are not divided into 3 controls per row?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I have designed this form but problem is that i want each three controls in one row each but in my code each control is in one row. Why?

I have put col-md-3 so 3 per row can be adjusted but still no. I read that col-md-3 takes three columns nd row is 12 columns so it should be 4 controls each row but still only one control per row. please help me on this. Improve it.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "InspectionReport", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div class="form-horizontal">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiReportNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiReportNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiReportNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Reference, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Reference, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Reference, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.PoNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.PoNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.PoNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.IssueDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.IssueDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.IssueDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionPhase, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionPhase, new List<SelectListItem>
                   {
                     new SelectListItem { Text = "India", Value = "1"},
                     new SelectListItem { Text = "USA", Value = "2"},
                     new SelectListItem { Text = "Sreelanka", Value = "3"}
                  }, "-Select-",
                  new
                  {
                      @Style = "Width:500px;height:40px;",
                      @class = "form-control input-lg"
                  })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionPhase, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InServiceInspection, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InServiceInspection)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InServiceInspection, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.NewInduction, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.NewInduction)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.NewInduction, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.HydrostaticTest, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.HydrostaticTest)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.HydrostaticTest, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.DimensionalCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.DimensionalCheck)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.DimensionalCheck, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ThicknessCheck, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ThicknessCheck)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ThicknessCheck, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Patrom, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Patrom)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Patrom, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Gvs, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Gvs)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Gvs, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Gvs, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Gvs)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Gvs, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.FinalOgraInspection, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.FinalOgraInspection)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.FinalOgraInspection, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.OmcClientRequirement, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.OmcClientRequirement)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.OmcClientRequirement, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryRegistrationNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryRegistrationNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryRegistrationNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TruckTractorManufacturerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TruckTractorManufacturerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TruckTractorManufacturerName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ClientName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ClientName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ClientName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Capacity, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Capacity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Capacity, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Omc, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Omc, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Omc, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.EngineNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.EngineNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.EngineNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryDimension, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryDimension, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryDimension, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ChassisNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ChassisNo, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.ChassisNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionPlace, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionPlace, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.InspectionPlace, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryEnginePower, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryEnginePower, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.TankLorryEnginePower, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.CarriageName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.CarriageName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.CarriageName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Brakes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Brakes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Brakes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.IsSatisfactory, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.IsSatisfactory)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.IsSatisfactory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Remarks, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Remarks, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Remarks, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Description, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-3">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <label> @ViewBag.Error</label>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-success btn-outline btn-block" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-save" style="font-size:medium"></i>  Add</button>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
                <button class="btn btn-default btn-block" type="button" onclick="window.location.href='@Url.Action("Index","Certificates")'"><i class="fa fa-remove" style="font-size:medium"></i>  Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

Comment: You need a container class wrapping the main content of your html. Then you need to nest your column classes inside rows. If you have 4 columns, then your outside div will be your row class and you'll nest 4 of your column classes within each row. You should look at the bootstrap documentation, they've done a good job making it comprehensible with many examples https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Comment: I made a quick codepen example: https://codepen.io/ciammarino/pen/vMJXZJ

Answer (score 0):

supposing you have all in a .container or .container-fluid div you should change this a bit.

First set a size for the form, then add .row divs wrapping your desired row and then, divs wrapping the individual content you want with the col-x class.

i.e:

```
<div class="form-horizontal col-md-12">

   <div class="row">

      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, new { @class = "form-control" })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })           
      </div>

      <div class="form-group col-md-3">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.InspectionReport.VelosiProjectNo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })           
      </div>

   </div>
```

Comment: It still has to be wrapped in a row. The OP asked how to stop the columns from stacking; all this does is stack the columns inside another column. See ex: https://codepen.io/ciammarino/pen/vMJXZJ

Comment: @ciammarino of course i forget to put it, i eddited the response, thanks.